# Dont proceed further if condition is not satisfied

Tags: c#

Below is my code

```
  if (drpMasterType.SelectedValue == "T_Post_Office" || drpMasterType.SelectedValue == "T_Driving_License_Type" || drpMasterType.SelectedValue == "IMD" || drpMasterType.SelectedValue == "SMMaster")
                    {
                        if (drpMasterType.SelectedValue == "IMD")
                        {

                        }
                    }

  DataTable newDt = new DataTable();
                    foreach (DataColumn DtColumn in dt.Columns)
                    {
                        DataColumn newDtColumn = new DataColumn();
                        newDtColumn.ColumnName = DtColumn.ColumnName;
                        newDt.Columns.Add(newDtColumn);
                    }
```

In above code, if my `if (drpMasterType.SelectedValue == "IMD")` this condition is not satisfying then i want get out of loop dont want to proceed from `DataTable newDt...`

Please tell me if any solution

Comment: A return will propably do your work

Comment: so the if itself is already part of a loop?

Comment: what about : ``if (drpMasterType.SelectedValue == "IMD"){ return;}``

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are in a void function. Then you could do this:

```
if (drpMasterType.SelectedValue == "IMD")
{
   return;
}
```

Comment: this is the opposite of Nitin's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25786314/1557027)? - I suppose Nitin is wrong? And why can't I use _break_ in a void function?

Answer (score 2):

usually you can use a

```
break;
```

to get out of a loop, have you considered this?

Answer (score 0):

For Void Function Use break and for other use return ;